# How can I determine the population of an Everquest 2 server?

Tags: everquest-2

During my wait for PlanetSide2 I found myself eager to re-join EQ2. With a new account and love of rogue(Was assassin maybe brigand this time for fear of no party), I'd join the most populated non-PVP server.

How can I determine the population and PVP status of an Everquest 2 server?

Comment: You can use http://www.soe.com/status/ to get an idea of the load on each server.  Highest load should equal highest population.

Comment: No actual number? Hmm...

Comment: I've edit your question to make to work on the site. Your original question was too localized in time, since the most populated server is going to always be changing. Due to that it would have been closed, but the revised question doesn't share any of these problems, and should stil answer you question :)

Comment: In general it's a good idea to ask one question per post, so instead of editing your question with the new question you have, it's better to ask a brand new question instead.

Comment: NVM I figured it out...